# Unable to install syslog-ng on amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, syslog-ng, amazon-linux-2

I have started EC2 instance from L=amazon linux 2 AMI.

I am trying to install syslog-ng with yum but I am getting error.

Commands used :

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
$ sudo yum install syslog-ng
```

AND

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng321/repo/epel-7/czanik-syslog-ng321-epel-7.repo"
$ sudo yum install --enablerepo=epel --assumeyes syslog-ng
```

But I am getting following error in both the cases:

```
    Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
215 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package syslog-ng.x86_64 0:3.23.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmaxminddb.so.0()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.23.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.23.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmaxminddb.x86_64 0:1.2.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package syslog-ng.x86_64 0:3.23.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.23.1-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: syslog-ng-3.23.1-1.el6.x86_64 (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:czanik:syslog-ng323epel6)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
cloud-init-19.3-44.amzn2.noarch has missing requires of rsyslog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with specific package and its able to install.

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=epel -y install syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: 3.5.6 is ancient, but works if you do not need any of the recent features.

Comment: @PeterCzanik, any other alternate way to install the latest?

Comment: @Gaurav Peter's instructions work correctly on Amazon Linux 2. Please make sure you add the EPEL 7 repository, not EPEL 6. The error message you shared shows that you are trying to install syslog-ng from `czanik:syslog-ng323epel6`.

Comment: how to add add the EPEL 7 repository

Comment: cd /etc/yum.repos.d/;
wget https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng335/repo/epel-7/czanik-syslog-ng335-epel-7.repo

Based on: https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/installing-syslog-ng-in-amazon-linux-2-including-graviton2

Answer (score 2):

I wrote these instructions a year ago: https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/installing-syslog-ng-in-amazon-linux-2-including-graviton2

I do not have any AWS accounts right now, but if they do not work, the I'll try to get one...

```
**Update:**
```

First of all: I double checked your report. You mention adding a repo for EPEL 7 syslog-ng 3.21, however the error below it is about syslog-ng 3.23 for EPEL 6.

OK, I got access. I followed my own instructions and it works:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$ syslog-ng -V
syslog-ng 3 (3.29.1)
Config version: 3.29
Installer-Version: 3.29.1
Revision: 
Compile-Date: Aug 29 2020 08:27:16
Module-Directory: /usr/lib64/syslog-ng
Module-Path: /usr/lib64/syslog-ng
Include-Path: /usr/share/syslog-ng/include
Available-Modules: add-contextual-data,affile,afprog,afsocket,afstomp,afuser,appmodel,basicfuncs,cef,confgen,cryptofuncs,csvparser,dbparser,disk-buffer,examples,graphite,hook-commands,json-plugin,kvformat,linux-kmsg-format,map-value-pairs,pseudofile,sdjournal,stardate,syslogformat,system-source,tags-parser,tfgetent,timestamp,xml,azure-auth-header,http
Enable-Debug: off
Enable-GProf: off
Enable-Memtrace: off
Enable-IPv6: on
Enable-Spoof-Source: on
Enable-TCP-Wrapper: on
Enable-Linux-Caps: on
Enable-Systemd: on

[ec2-user@ip-xxx ~]$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

And tried to latest version (3.35), and that works as well.

Comment: Yes, I follow your blog post, but the command `yum install syslog-ng` gives same error

Comment: Tried the steps on fresh EC2, it got installed thanks